# "Host key verification failed"?

Tags: ssh

Well, I'm working with virtual machines and I was trying to establish connection between client and server by ssh (from client to server). I installed ssh in both machine and I restarted too. It was not a problem. But, when I tried to connect from client with:

```
ssh -p 22 myservername@myserverip
```

It said: "Host key verification failed". It's always the same, whatever I've done.

This is the second time I've tried it (I uninstalled the two ubuntus and installed again)

What could I do to establish that connection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you reinstall a machine it gets a new ssh host key, but the old one is still stored in your key file.

Open `~/.ssh/known_hosts` with an editor and remove the lines containing the problematic host keys.

Alternatively you can use `ssh-keygen` to remove the problematic entries automatically.

```
ssh-keygen -R myserverip
ssh-keygen -R myservername
```

You'll be asked to verify the new host keys the next time you connect.

Answer (score 1):

here is the answer of this problem

used `-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no` in the command

```
scp -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -r -i openssh.pem test.txt root@x.x.x.x:/home/
```

fixed the issue after adding -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no